# C# Winform DataGridView New added row value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I retrieve the value of a new row? Which action/event can I use to get these values?

```
(e.Row.Cells["COLUMN NAME"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Can you explain what you want to know?

Comment: There is a `RowsAdded` event, maybe that's what you need. Try to explain your problem with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you want to retrieve the contents of a cell of the DataGridView, an example and use the event rowValidated, see example below.

```
         private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null)
            {
                this.textBox1.Text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Column1"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

If you mean another, possibly explaining what vouoi get.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks you for your response. i just want to Add and Modify the value of my grid.